# What's with web applications sending notifications via delaying loads?

Tags: ajax, web-applications, httpwebrequest

I've noticed on a lot of applications recently, such as Google Docs and Facebook, that JavaScript is being used to load a file which doesn't load until the website needs to send you a notification.

Essentially, they're using an HTTP request to a file, and then the server which handles the file doesn't respond to the request (or may respond but not send the content) until the server wants to send a notification (such as a new IM or a document update) to the user.

I haven't been able to find much on the web about the best practices for doing this. It seems to be a relatively new technique.

I'm looking into doing this myself and would like to read more on it. Does this have a name? Are there established best practices for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start reading about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technology. And here is a good Comet Server, [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/): Ajax Push Engine

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! (sorry for the long response time)